# Is there a way to format the spring boot build information on the info endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot allows for exposing git commit and build information on the actuator `/info` endpoint. I have used the [1.5.10.RELEASE integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-git) for setting this up.

However the date on the info endpoint is being rendered as a timestamp:

`{"git":{
  "commit":{
    "time":1520441384000,
    ...`

Is there a way to customize this format into something more human readable?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Jackson on how to serialize dates in your application.properties (or application.yml respectively):

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Make sure though, you use the latest version of the plugin, as the generated dateformat default was recently switched.

Here's a full setup:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>git-info</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties, you can specify the format in your application.properties, e.g.

```
gitProperties {
    dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"
    dateFormatTimeZone = "PST"
}
```